# Replace text with own icons on twitter bootstrap menu/nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my own icons that i've saved as pngs as nav/menu options instead of the current text I have on my bootstrap menu, but i'm not sure what part of the css i need to change? below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Explore Canterbury</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#Locations">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Photos">Photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#Locations">Locations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Photos"><span class="photosIcon"></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#Info"><span class="infoIcon"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.photosIcon {
  background-image:url(urlToYourImage.png);
  width:100px;
  heigth:100px;
}

.infoIcon {
  background-image:url(urlToYourImage.png);
  width:100px;
  heigth:100px;
}
```

Then you have to code the final touches to the icons until they are how you want it.

Comment: Hey, they don't seem to be appearing? http://sc580.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/ExploreCanterbury/